# What is the definition of the average distance between the sun and the earth?

Tags: definition, solar-system

What is the definition of the average distance between the sun and the earth?

Let $r(t)$ be the distance between the sun and the earth at $t$.
Is the definition of the average distance between the sun and the earth $\frac{\int_{0}^{365} r(t) dt}{365}$ ?

If so, I can compute the average distance between the sun and the earth as follows.

$r(t) + r'(t) = 2 a$ for all $t$.

$2a = \frac{\int_{0}^{365} 2 a dt}{365} = \frac{\int_{0}^{365} r(t) + r'(t) dt}{365} = \frac{\int_{0}^{365} r(t) dt}{365} + \frac{\int_{0}^{365} r'(t) dt}{365}$.
By symmetry, $\frac{\int_{0}^{365} r(t) dt}{365} = \frac{\int_{0}^{365} r'(t) dt}{365}$.
So, $\frac{\int_{0}^{365} r(t) dt}{365} = a$.

Comment: The distance between the Earth and the Sun averaged over some period of time is not a useful concept. The distance averaged over a period of 36 days is even less useful. By the way, what is your symbol $r'(t)$?

Comment: If by $r'(t)$ you mean the point on the Keplerian ellipse diametrically opposed to $r(t)$, then $r(t)+r'(t) \ne 2a$, where $a$ is the semi-major axis length of the ellipse. It is instead $2a\frac{1-e^2}{1-e^2\cos^2(\theta(t))}$, which for $0<e<1$ is almost always less than $2a$.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible definitions for the "average" of any quantity. Which one is "correct" depends on the context in which it is being used. You have not provided any context so your question cannot be answered.

What you have defined is the time-averaged distance between the Earth and the Sun. This averages the Earth-Sun distance over a complete year at equal small time intervals.

An alternative is the average over equal angular increments measured from the Sun. Another is the average over equal increments of distance around the Earth's orbit. Another is the radius of a circle which has the same area as the Earth's elliptical orbit.

Kepler's Third Law relates the periods of planetary orbits to their distances from the Sun. In this case the **semi-major axis** of the elliptical orbit is used. This is half the distance between the furthest points in the orbit. It takes no account of the eccentricity of the orbit. **This is the definition of average used in tables of the average distances of planets from the Sun.**

All of these definitions would give the same answer if the Earth moved at constant speed around a perfect circle centred on the Sun.